# "Procedure created with compilation error" cause by ORA-00936

Tags: java, sql, oracle, procedure

I've created a procedure:

```
Create or Replace Procedure GetTotalEmployeesByDepartment
(
deptno in Employees.Department_Id%Type,
totalEmployees out number
)
as
begin
select cout(*) into totalEmployees from Employees
where Department_Id = deptno;
end;
/
```

with result:

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

As I typed:

```
show errors;
```

Command line shown:

```
LINE/COL   ERROR
8/1        PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
8/13       PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Do you know what may goes wrong? Why SQL ignose "cout" statement and missing "*"?

Answer (score 1):

Should it be not cou**n**t(*) with **n**:)

Comment: better than another possible typo